# How to edit Caja's / Nautilus' "open with list"?

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager, caja

Due to testing several programs I've ended up with a lot of entries on Caja's "open with list" menu when opening files. How does one edit that list in order to remove undesired entries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- right click on the file
- click on "Open with another application"
- right click on the association you want to remove
- click on "Forget association"

The information is saved in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

And is shared also with `Files` and other programs. So you can use `Files` to edit those associations too and they will work in Caja.

Comment: Not working... No menu showed up after right click on app list item...

Comment: @RookieOne I edited the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Not working for me.